# Drop down from array of objects

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-2.0, knockout-mapping-plugin, knockout-validation, knockout-mvc

Hi I am newbie in Knockout Js.Can anyone please explain me how can I create drop down from array of Objects.I want the text and the value of drop down should be different.And the objects are in Key Value Pair.

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: Start with the [documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/options-binding.html) and then come back with a specific question if you are still having problems.

Comment: hey i am able to display with simple array but not with the array of object...please help me

Comment: Look at example 3 in the documentation. It's a drop-down with javascript objects.

Comment: Matt i am really not able to get it can you please simplify for me please..Actually i stored the data in array..now it became the array of objects..i am not able to iterate and display values

Comment: Since *nobody* can see any of your code, how do you expect anybody to simplify? Include the *relevant* bits of your code *in the question*

Comment: If i open my array of objects my data is  like:                                                                                description: "Document Request"
formatMessage: ""
key: ""
requestMessage: ""
serviceCharge: ""
subjectMessage: ""
value: "DR"

Comment: I want a drop down of text as Document Request and the vale of DR

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<select data-bind="options: nameOfOptionsCollection, optionsText: key, optionsValue: value, value: observable></select>
```

http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/options-binding.html

- options is where the array or object that you want to list
  in the dropdown will go
- optionsText is the text in the dropdown
- optionsValue will be the value attribute on the each option
- value is the observable in your viewmodel that you want to bind to this dropdown

Try to check http://knockoutjs.com when you have questions about knockout.